# Rails: Make different references to a DB row refer to the same Ruby object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have the following model relationship:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
end
```

I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925785/rails-associations-problems-with-altering-values-and-too-much-caching) that Rails will return me a *copy* of the object representing a database row, meaning that:

```
p = Player.find(:first)
c = p.cards[0]
c.player.object_id == p.object_id # => false
```

...and therefore if the Player model modifies `self`, and the Card model modifies `self.player` in the same request, then the modifications won't take any notice of each other and the last-saved one will overwrite the others.

I'd like to work around this (presumably with some form of caching), so that all requests for a Player with a given id would return the same object (identical object_ids), thereby allowing both models to edit the same object without having to perform a database save-and-reload. I have three questions:

1. Is there already a plugin or gem to do this?
2. Are there good reasons why I *shouldn't* do this?
3. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Can you better explain the use case of editing the player from both the player object and the card object?

Comment: See the linked question. Suppose it costs a player 1 action to play a Card, and there is a certain type of card which grants 2 actions when you play it. Then I want to do `self.actions -= 1` in Player, and `player.actions += 1` in the Card subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is supported in Rails 3.x. You can use the `:inverse_of` option for the `has_many` association for example. [Documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) (search for `:inverse_of` and `Bi-directional associations`).

Comment: Ok, yes, that looks like it works. All I'll need to do is go through and replace some constructs (I have separate `has_many` relationships for hand_cards and deck_cards) with proper association extensions. Which I should probably do anyway. Bounty is yours once I've given that a go.